# How can I answer to shell questions

Tags: python, django, cmd

I am trying to create a simple program to create a superuser for django but I can't answer to the questions after that.

```
os.popen('python manage.py createsuperuser')
```

when this line of code runs, the interpreter asks me to enter a username like the picture in below :

[image]

How can I answer that using some variables in python codes and not by hand.
I want the program to handle it not a human.

Also I can't really work with the manage.py file because then I have to change the content in the library which is not good.

```
def create_superuser(self) :
    username = self.lineEdit_4.text()
    password = self.lineEdit_3.text()
    if len(username) == 0 or len(password) == 0 :
        return
    email = self.lineEdit_5.text()
    _chdir(self.base_directory)
    script = f"python manage.py createsuperuser --username {username} --password {password} --noinput --email '{email}'"
    print('starting')
    _popen(script)
    print('done')
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't do this in a python/django script so that you have access to the User model and don't need to call the management command

Comment: Is there another way to create a superuser ?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager.create_superuser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use 'python manage.py shell -c':

```
python manage.py shell -c "from django.contrib.auth.models import User; User.objects.create_superuser('admin', 'admin@example.com', 'adminpass')"
```

I suggest you create a management command (name the command file `createsuperuser2`) in

```
your_app/
    __init__.py
    models.py
    management/
        __init__.py
        commands/
            __init__.py
            createsuperuser2.py
    tests.py
    views.py
```

Inside `createsuperuser2` write following code

```
from django.contrib.auth.management.commands import createsuperuser
from django.core.management import CommandError


class Command(createsuperuser.Command):
    help = 'Crate a superuser, and allow password to be provided'

    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        super(Command, self).add_arguments(parser)
        parser.add_argument(
            '--password', dest='password', default=None,
            help='Specifies the password for the superuser.',
        )

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        password = options.get('password')
        username = options.get('username')
        database = options.get('database')

        if password and not username:
            raise CommandError("--username is required if specifying --password")

        super(Command, self).handle(*args, **options)

        if password:
            user = self.UserModel._default_manager.db_manager(database).get(username=username)
            user.set_password(password)
            user.save()
```

Then pass command like

```
python manage.py createsuperuser2 --username test1 --password 123321 --noinput --email 'blank@email.com'
```

Comment: Why in the name of all that is holy would you bother invoking it as a separate command if you can just invoke `User.objects.create_superuser` directly? You're risking security vulnerabilities passing stuff to the shell and also seriously degrading performance by opening more processes.